# fixing the error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError' while installing pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, java-8

I have to install a specific version of pyspark (version spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2.0) but when I run either the 'pyspark' command or the 'spark-shell' command in CMD, I get the error.

```
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.(package.scala:825)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.(package.scala)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.(SparkSubmit.scala:990)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:990)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @66d18979
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.(Platform.java:56)
... 13 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Apachespark\spark\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in 
SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
File "C:\Apachespark\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 319, in _ensure_initialized
SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
File "C:\Apachespark\spark\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 105, in launch_gateway
raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

I have searched for solutions and I've tried them but they didn't work. It shouldn't be that hard.

Can someone please help me?

**Here's what I've done so far**

I have these software installed:
(NOTE: I have to install these specific versions because I am using them for a college course)

- Java version "1.8.0_261"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
- Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- pycharm 2022 community edition
- spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2
- winutils.exe (hadoop 3.2.0)

I have created a folder for the spark zip file in my C:\ drive called "ApacheSpark". Then I extract the zip file and create a "hadoop\bin" folder inside my spark-3.0.0 folder for the winutils.exe file.

I've set their HOME and path variables as follows:
(NOTE: I set the HOME variables from the system variables NOT from the user variables)

SPARK_HOME  --> C:\ApacheSpark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2

HADOOP_HOME  --> C:\ApacheSpark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2\hadoop

paths:

%SPARK_HOME%\bin

%HADOOP_HOME%\bin

After doing all these steps and entering the commands, I get this error:

'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError'

---

Also before placing the winutils.exe file inside the spark folder, I had it in a separate folder but still in my C:\ drive. That way, I would get the following error:

'pyspark' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages.  See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I realized I never got any errors regarding python and this was only a java error. I set my path and home variables in my System variables but I saw that I had previously defined a path and home for a previously installed java 17 in my User variables. After changing them in my user vars to the ones in my system vars, pyspark ran smoothly.